# To fetch list of Sobject in lightning component and display it in dropdown list

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Hi all I am new to lightning component and I have gone through many blogs of it but still have a confusion can anyone please help me.
I have been given a scenario where I have to make a lightning component which will show the list of all the objects in org in form of dropdown list. So please help .

```
<aura:component controller="QueryBuilderLightning">
 <aura:attribute name="options" type="List" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
<lightning:select name="Objects" label="Select object:" aura:id="onjId" value="{!v.getObjectName}">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.objects}" var="object">
        <option text="{!object.label}"  selected="{!option.selected}"/>
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
</aura:component>
```

---

```
public class QueryBuilderLightning {
@AuraEnabled
    public static List<String> getObjectName(){
        List<String> objects=new List<String>();
       Map<String,Schema.SObjectType> objMap=Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        for(String s:objMap.keyset()){
            objects.addAll(objMap.keyset());
        }
        return objects;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: can you edit the existing question and post it there m, Thanks

Comment: @maria Please [edit] your question to include your code and a *specific question*. see [ask]. Don't use comments for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is missed important things like server call, attribute for `v.objects`, in your case you can use `options` attribute also for all Sobjectnames i would recommend to go through David shared blog for especially lightning development. here is simple code for your use case. let me know if have any issue.

**cmp**

```
    <aura:component controller="QueryBuilderLightning" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" 
            access="global" >
   <aura:attribute name="options" type="List" />
   <aura:attribute name="selectedValue" type="String" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
<lightning:select name="Objects" label="Select object:" aura:id="onjId" value="{!v.selectedValue}">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.options}" var="objectname">
        <option value="{!objectname}" text="{!objectname}" />  
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
</aura:component>
```

**cmpController**

```
({
init: function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getObjectName");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {           
            var allValues = response.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.options", allValues);
        }                    
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
            var errors = response.getError();
            if (errors) {
                if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                    console.log("Error message: " + 
                             errors[0].message);
                }
            } 
            else {
                console.log("Unknown Error");
            }
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
 }
})
```

**ApexController**

```
    public class QueryBuilderLightning {
@AuraEnabled
    public static List<String> getObjectName(){
        List<String> objects=new List<String>();
       List<Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values();  
        for(SObjectType sot:gd){
           objects.add(sot.getDescribe().getName());
           objects.sort();  
        }
        return objects;
    }
}
```

Comment: ya sure thank you for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Your code is referring to a component attribute `{!v.objects}`, which does not exist. To retrieve data from an Apex controller, your client-side Lightning controller (in JavaScript) must make a [server-side action call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm) to asynchronous retrieve this data. You can't invoke an Apex controller method via `{!v.getObjectName}`.

Then, it'd populate that data into an attribute that you would declare in the component:

```
 <aura:attribute name="objects" type="String[]" />
```

Your `<option>` markup is also in need of some changes:

```
    <option text="{!object.label}"  selected="{!option.selected}"/>
```

You're not returning objects with properties from Apex but a list of Strings, so there's no property `label`.

Comment: ok thank you but can u be more specific and explain as i am new i am finding it a bit difficult

Comment: Hi @maria, there's a detailed example in the documentation I linked. I'd suggest starting there. Is there a specific point you'd welcome more clarification on?

Comment: Thank u i will read it and try to make the changes

Comment: But i want to ask whether i am using the correct way to do it

Comment: @maria Your Apex is fine. Your Lightning is what you need to work on.

Comment: Thank u for you suggestion @david